# How to remove comments following # in a text string in R

Tags: r, comments

I have a text string variable, e.g.

```
string <- ' a=1, # number a is equal to 1
            b=2, # number b is equal to 2'
```

I cannot evaluate those equations before removing the comments following #.
Is there any function designed to do that? or should I use regex to process that?

Comment: If you are using `eval(parse(text = string))` I think the problem is the commas not the `#`s.

Comment: I agree with you. My algorithm is to remove the line return first. Then the comment and the following equation concatenate together. That cause error. I might need to optimize my algorithm thirst. Thank you, Gregor.

Comment: Regarding the comma, I use it as delimiter to separate those equations by **base:strsplit (string, ",") **.  This is one of algorithms and I believe some smarter way must exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use regex:

```
gsub(pattern = "#[^\\\n]*", replacement = "", x = string)
# [1] " a=1, \n            b=2, "
```

Explanation: `"#[^\\\n]*"` matches a `#` followed by anything other than a new line `\n`.

I'm pretty skeptical of *why* you're doing this. There's probably a better way to accomplish your goal...

Comment: Normally, people just want to evaluate:  a = 1 and b=2.
In that case, you can simply use: 
 var <-  c(a=1,  # number a is equal to 1
               b=2)
# comments do not matter here.
However, my ultimate goal is to evaluate:   a=1,  b= a/2.
If I can it the same way, 
var <-  c(a=1,  # number a is equal to 1
               b=a/2   )
Then, this would run into error because a is not defined.

Comment: Then I come up with:
string <- ' a=1, # number a is equal to 1
            b=a/2, # number b is equal to 2'
Once the comments are removed, with some other functions, I can evaluate every equation one by one. First a =1, then b=a/2.   The issue that a is not defined do not exist anymore.

Comment: Yes, but probably you don't need to be using `eval` at all... there is almost certainly a better way to get/store those values than in strings.

Comment: I found "#[^\n]*" works equally well. Why do you need the extra \\

Comment: Hi Gregor, Could you kindly offer hints on the better way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `stringr` package:

```
str <- strsplit(string, split = "\n")[[1]]
str_trim(str_split_fixed(str, "#|;", 2)[, 1])

#[1] "a=1," "b=2,"
```

Or if, for example, `str <- "a=1, # number a is equal to 1"`, then

```
str_trim(str_split_fixed(str, "#|;", 2)[, 1])

#[1] "a=1,"
```